# React-Hooks: How to sort data in ascending & descending order and show in reusable data table component

Tags: reactjs, api, sorting, react-hooks

In my application, I want to create a reusable data table component. Data is coming from the Backend, for that data I need to do the sort. The data are numbers & strings. Now I want to show data in Ascending order and  Descending order button. Here is my data table code:

```
//Table Component
const Table = ({ headers, data }) => {
return (
 <table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     {headers.map(head => (
       <th>{head}</th>
     ))}
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
  {data.map(row => (
    <tr>
      {headers.map(head => (
        <td>{row[head]}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
   ))}
 </tbody>
</table>


//app.js

 export default function App() {
 const headers = ['userId', 'id', 'title', 'body'];
 
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        setData(data);
    };
    
    getPosts();
}, []);

 const filteredData = slice.filter(
    post => post.title.toLowerCase().includes(keyword) || post.body.toLowerCase().includes(keyword),
);

const onInputChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setKeyword(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
};
 

  return (
   <div>
     div className="table-search-form">
              <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Search..."
                  onChange={onInputChange}
                  />
                  </div>
    <DataTable headers={headers} posts={filteredData} />
   </div>
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution using a data-table package. Here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component-extensions